# Updating Account Record on the basis of Externel_id field

Tags: data-import-wizard

I have create 2 external custom field in Account object, now i want to compare records on the basis of these external fields. But i am not able to find any option in import wizard where i can set these type of option for comparison.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000003803&language=en_US):

> The option to use an External Id for matching is not available for the
>   Lead Import Wizard, nor the Accounts & Contacts Import Wizard.